# Re/Create an immutable object that contains an immutable object list

Tags: java, android, immutability

**Background**

I am trying to create an immutable object that contains a list of immutable objects, as well as object type totals within the list.

I created a slightly sudo gist to try and show what I mean.

[Gist - Adjusting an immutable object that contains an immutable object list.](https://gist.github.com/JonathanMerritt/c9e0daf74308ea12085af8354cf87844)

**Explanation**

My example shows how I'm currently doing it, it does work. However not for all cases.

My [VeggieCartView](https://gist.github.com/JonathanMerritt/c9e0daf74308ea12085af8354cf87844#file-veggiecart_veggiecartview-java) will have a recyclerview that gets filled with a new/saved [VeggieCart](https://gist.github.com/JonathanMerritt/c9e0daf74308ea12085af8354cf87844#file-veggiecart_veggiecart-java).

Each VeggieCart has a list of veggies. Veggie totals etc...

I then have a helper class [VeggieChanger](https://gist.github.com/JonathanMerritt/c9e0daf74308ea12085af8354cf87844#file-veggiecart_veggiechanger-java), it contains an `rx.Consumer<Veggie[]>` that gets set and accepts any 1:1 veggie changes from the veggie views.

The VeggieCartView sets the consumer so when any one veggie changes, it creates an updated cart using the changes' corresponding cart factory method. The adapter is used to change/retrieve its list.

**Working and not**

This works well for changing one at a time, however batching changes is throwing concurrency exceptions.

I realize my gist is not runnable and doesn't show most boilerplate, and that I may be fundamentally wrong with some or all of my approaches. With that said I still hope someone can give me advice on how to better implement what I'm trying to do.

If more information is needed to understand, please ask. Thank you for anybody who does have help to offer,

Jon.

Comment: 'Adjust an immutable object' is a contradiction in terms. The rest is frankly incomprehensible.

Comment: @EJP Yikes lol. You are right, my questions title is not correct, in terms of the literal meaning anyway. I'll change it. Maybe 'Re/Create an immutable...' As far as everything else being incomprehensible, that's clearly just a snide remark. Not sure how that would be helpful at all. If it is meant to be helpful, please elaborate, otherwise not sure why you mentioned it. Thanks for the title tip all the same though.

Comment: @EJP Ok, thanks for the drive-by!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out my main issue.

By adding this to my VeggieCartView:

```
public void bagAllCanned() {
  final Veggie[] canned = new Veggie[cart.canTotal()];
  final Veggie[] bagged = new Veggie[canned.length];
  int t = 0;
  final List<Veggie> veggies = cart.veggies();
  for (int i = 0; i < veggies.size(); i++) {
    final Veggie veggie = veggies.get(i);
    if (veggie.canned()) {
      canned[t] = veggie;
      if (veggie instanceof Potato)
      bagged[t] = Potato.can(veggie);
      else if (veggie instanceof Tomato)
        bagged[t] = Tomato.can(veggie);
      t++;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < canned.length; i++) {
    veggieChange(canned[i], bagged[i]);
  }
}
```

It fixes the concurrency errors.

I'm still unsure if my approach is correct or not. So even though the question is mostly answered, opinions are still VERY welcome.